# How to ensure my data is saved on Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am storing my data in Firebase database in my Android app. However, I am not sure how to check if my data is saved on database and show appropriate message. So far, I tried to check the unique ID created by push and see if it is null or not. But it did not work for me. Any other suggestion?

```
private void createData(String name){
    SnapShotModel ssm = new SnapShotModel(name);
    myRef.push().setValue(ssm);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        }
        builder.setTitle("ERROR!")
                .setMessage("Error in saving data. Please try again.")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to ensure my data is saved on Firebase?

You can be sure if add a complete listener after you calling `setValue()` method like this:

```
myRef.push().setValue(ssm).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Object successfully added");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase db;

onCreate
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

DatabaseReference readDb = db.getReference("Your Channel Name");
    readDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

When you read this way in your application, you are connected to your database.

```
DatabaseReference writeDb = db.getReference("Your Channel Name");
writeDb.setValue("Value");
```

this way you can write

Note: google-services.json don't forget to add.

and build.grandle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
```

Comment: I am writing in database and want to make sure my data is committed into my firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to know when your data has been committed, you can add a completion listener. Check [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback)

```
ref.setValue("I'm writing data", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError == null) {
            Show dialog
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems Firebase is deprecated.